# Asymmetric errors on cluster size distributions

Tags: symmetry, errors-in-variables

I have a question that might seem simple, but I'm unsure how to address it.
For an analysis on pixel detectors, I am extracting a histogram similar to the ones attached, focusing on the cluster size projected. This histogram represents the number of rows or columns (i.e., pixels) that my clusters have for each recorded event.
[image: Row]
[image: Col]

Certainly, by definition, such a distribution is strongly asymmetric since values less than 1 are not possible, and each bin represents exactly an integer value. Furthermore, as you can see from the logarithmic scale, the distribution is effectively divided into only two or three bins.

Would anyone be able to suggest a method for estimating valid asymmetric errors in this case? Clearly, the minimum cannot be less than 1.

Thank you to anyone willing to help me out.

Best regards,
Massimiliano